# Spring security HttpSessionRequestCache saved request not persisted between requests

Tags: spring-security, spring-session, spring-authorization-server

I'm building a new authentication filter to use with spring authorization server and have copied the code from FormLoginConfigurer to configure my filter.

When I run the code using `.formLogin()`, the `HttpSessionRequestCache` saves the request when redirecting user to the `/login` endpoint and after successful authentication the saved request is fetched from the `HttpSessionRequestCache` and redirects back.

However, when I use my filter instead, the `HttpSessionRequestCache` still stores the request on the session, but when after successful authentication the `HttpSessionRequestCache` can't find the saved request on the current session..

Here's some of the code:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());   // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0

        // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
        // authorization endpoint
        http.exceptionHandling(exceptions ->
                        exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(
                                /*new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login")))*/
                                new AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint("/auth/start")))
                // Accept access tokens for User Info and/or Client Registration
                .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize ->
                        authorize.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/start", HttpMethod.GET.name())).permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                /*.formLogin();*/
                .apply(new CustomConfigurer<>());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
    }
}
```

My configurer:

```
public class CustomConfigurer<H extends HttpSecurityBuilder<H>> extends
        AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer<H, CustomConfigurer<H>, CustomAuthenticationFilter> {

    @Override
    public CustomConfigurer<H> loginPage(String loginPage) {
        return super.loginPage(loginPage);
    }

    /**
     * Forward Authentication Failure Handler
     * @param forwardUrl the target URL in case of failure
     * @return the {@link CustomConfigurer} for additional customization
     */
    public CustomConfigurer<H> failureForwardUrl(String forwardUrl) {
        failureHandler(new ForwardAuthenticationFailureHandler(forwardUrl));
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Forward Authentication Success Handler
     * @param forwardUrl the target URL in case of success
     * @return the {@link CustomConfigurer} for additional customization
     */
    public CustomConfigurer<H> successForwardUrl(String forwardUrl) {
        successHandler(new ForwardAuthenticationSuccessHandler(forwardUrl));
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(H http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider(getRpApiService(http)));

        CustomAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter(
                authenticationManager, getRegisteredClientRepository(http));
        this.setAuthenticationFilter(authenticationFilter);
        this.loginProcessingUrl("/auth/collect");
        http.addFilterAfter(authenticationFilter, LogoutFilter.class);
        super.init(http);
    }

    @Override
    protected RequestMatcher createLoginProcessingUrlMatcher(String loginProcessingUrl) {
        return new AntPathRequestMatcher(loginProcessingUrl, "GET");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot of custom code being used based on your config. Any way to break the problem down into smaller pieces? Since the "forward" handlers you set up seem like they could cause problems, you could test your success/failure handlers in isolation by configuring them on `.formLogin()`. If that doesn't uncover the issue, it's likely your custom filter.